# What is the best approach of using cache in ASP.NET project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, browser

I am working in a project in ASP.NET.

I want to cache the username for the first time when the user logs in. E.g: If the current user is logged in and visiting a particular page for the first time, there will be a popup window display, otherwise nothing happens.

The username should be stored in the client browser and remain valid until the user closes the browser.

My question is, what is the best approach of doing this?

Any limitations if I am using ASP.Net Cache to store the username? 
For example:

```
Cache["myCache"] = username;
```

and remove the item from the cache when page loads for the first time.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     Cache.Remove("myCache");
}
```

This is open for any comments. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `HttpCookie` and set the expiration as needed:

> If you do not set the cookie's expiration, the cookie is created but
>   it is not stored on the user's hard disk. Instead, the cookie is
>   maintained as part of the user's session information. When the user
>   closes the browser, the cookie is discarded.

[ASP.NET Cookies Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
//write
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
myCookie["Font"] = "Arial";
myCookie["Color"] = "Blue";
//myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

//read
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    string userSettings;
    if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"] != null)
    { userSettings = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"]; }
}
```

[How to: Write a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[How to: Read a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This might work in as what I need, is IE setting will affect the storing of data in HttpCookie? like disable scripting or any other plug in

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using the Session instead?  The cache is shared over all sessions would require you to remove the item once the session ends.  The Session doesn't suffer this problem, it is aligned with each user's session directly and is removed automatically when the session ends.  NOTE: I'm assuming that you're talking about a display name, not the user's login name.  That should be available via `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

As for showing the pop up, you might want to use cookies for this.  Have some javascript that runs on the page that checks for the cookie, displays the popup if it's not there, and then sets the cookie (as a session cookie) so that the popup isn't show again.  A cookie could also be used (not a session cookie) if you only wanted the popup to show the first time someone logs in or only periodically on login, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply, correct me if I'm wrong, if not mistaken Session consumed server's memory, this will burden the server since the application might access thousand of users.

Comment: You are correct. Session does use the server's memory. It would depend on the amount of memory and data being stored in memory whether or not this would be an issue.

Comment: @sams5817 - (a) it won't consume any more memory than the cache since it's unique per user anyway and (b) you can configure it to use SQL Server (or a session state server) to store the session instead of keeping it in memory.  The latter option isn't available for the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use caching for this. Rather, ASP.NET has support for Membership and Roles. I'd use that to manage your membership unless you'd like to use the cookie solution listed above. Regarding the page pop up, if this is only for one page, you can use a cookie or setting on the users' profile.